# Spring security exception during login attempt

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I implemented an authentication micro service  for authentication and authorization process and my implementation based on spring cloud architecture.

If I run authentication service on my IntelliJ IDE there is no any exception, it works fine. But I build executable jar and run. It throws an exception mentioned below.

When I send login request and I get following exception;

```
2019-04-26 08:51:55.169 DEBUG 13332 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/token at position 5 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'BasicAuthenticationFilter'
2019-04-26 08:51:55.170 DEBUG 13332 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter  : Basic Authentication Authorization header found for user 'oms-web-ui'
2019-04-26 08:51:55.170 DEBUG 13332 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.s.s.authentication.ProviderManager     : Authentication attempt using org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider
2019-04-26 08:51:55.357 DEBUG 13332 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@2237ed4a
2019-04-26 08:51:55.357 DEBUG 13332 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
2019-04-26 08:51:55.360 ERROR 13332 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet]      : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/uaa] threw exception [Filter execution threw an exception] with root cause

java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource.getTarget(SimpleBeanTargetSource.java:35) ~[spring-aop-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:193) ~[spring-aop-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy181.loadClientByClientId(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor142.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343) ~[spring-aop-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:197) ~[spring-aop-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:136) ~[spring-aop-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:124) ~[spring-aop-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy181.loadClientByClientId(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor142.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343) ~[spring-aop-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:197) ~[spring-aop-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:136) ~[spring-aop-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:124) ~[spring-aop-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy181.loadClientByClientId(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor142.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343) ~[spring-aop-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:197) ~[spring-aop-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:136) ~[spring-aop-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:124) ~[spring-aop-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy181.loadClientByClientId(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor142.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343) ~[spring-aop-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:197) ~[spring-aop-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:136) ~[spring-aop-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:124) ~[spring-aop-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy181.loadClientByClientId(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor142.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343) ~[spring-aop-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:197) ~[spring-aop-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:136) ~[spring-aop-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:124) ~[spring-aop-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy181.loadClientByClientId(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor142.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343) ~[spring-aop-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:197) ~[spring-aop-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:136) ~[spring-aop-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:124) ~[spring-aop-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]

2019-04-26 08:51:55.363 DEBUG 13332 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/oauth/token']
2019-04-26 08:51:55.363 DEBUG 13332 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/error'; against '/oauth/token'
2019-04-26 08:51:55.363 DEBUG 13332 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/oauth/token_key']
2019-04-26 08:51:55.363 DEBUG 13332 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/error'; against '/oauth/token_key'
2019-04-26 08:51:55.363 DEBUG 13332 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/oauth/check_token']
2019-04-26 08:51:55.363 DEBUG 13332 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/error'; against '/oauth/check_token'
2019-04-26 08:51:55.363 DEBUG 13332 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : No matches found
2019-04-26 08:51:55.363 DEBUG 13332 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error at position 1 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
2019-04-26 08:51:55.363 DEBUG 13332 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error at position 2 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2019-04-26 08:51:55.363 DEBUG 13332 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error at position 3 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
2019-04-26 08:51:55.363 DEBUG 13332 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error at position 4 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
2019-04-26 08:51:55.363 DEBUG 13332 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', GET]
2019-04-26 08:51:55.363 DEBUG 13332 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'POST /error' doesn't match 'GET /logout
2019-04-26 08:51:55.363 DEBUG 13332 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', POST]
2019-04-26 08:51:55.363 DEBUG 13332 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/error'; against '/logout'
2019-04-26 08:51:55.363 DEBUG 13332 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', PUT]
2019-04-26 08:51:55.363 DEBUG 13332 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'POST /error' doesn't match 'PUT /logout
2019-04-26 08:51:55.363 DEBUG 13332 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', DELETE]
2019-04-26 08:51:55.363 DEBUG 13332 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'POST /error' doesn't match 'DELETE /logout
2019-04-26 08:51:55.363 DEBUG 13332 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : No matches found
2019-04-26 08:51:55.363 DEBUG 13332 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error at position 5 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter'
2019-04-26 08:51:55.363 DEBUG 13332 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.s.s.o.p.a.BearerTokenExtractor         : Token not found in headers. Trying request parameters.
2019-04-26 08:51:55.363 DEBUG 13332 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.s.s.o.p.a.BearerTokenExtractor         : Token not found in request parameters.  Not an OAuth2 request.
2019-04-26 08:51:55.363 DEBUG 13332 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] p.a.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter : No token in request, will continue chain.
2019-04-26 08:51:55.363 DEBUG 13332 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error at position 6 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
2019-04-26 08:51:55.363 DEBUG 13332 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error at position 7 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
2019-04-26 08:51:55.363 DEBUG 13332 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error at position 8 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
2019-04-26 08:51:55.363 DEBUG 13332 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@e1fa64a8: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 217.78.106.110; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
2019-04-26 08:51:55.363 DEBUG 13332 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error at position 9 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
2019-04-26 08:51:55.363 DEBUG 13332 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error at position 10 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
2019-04-26 08:51:55.363 DEBUG 13332 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error at position 11 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
2019-04-26 08:51:55.363 DEBUG 13332 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /error; Attributes: [#oauth2.throwOnError(authenticated)]
2019-04-26 08:51:55.364 DEBUG 13332 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@e1fa64a8: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 217.78.106.110; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
2019-04-26 08:51:55.364 DEBUG 13332 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased       : Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@486e94f0, returned: -1
2019-04-26 08:51:55.365 DEBUG 13332 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point

org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
        at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:84) ~[spring-security-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:233) ~[spring-security-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:124) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) [spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) [spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170) [spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) [spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1468) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_201]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_201]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_201]

2019-04-26 08:51:55.365 DEBUG 13332 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Calling Authentication entry point.
2019-04-26 08:51:55.367 DEBUG 13332 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] s.s.o.p.e.DefaultOAuth2ExceptionRenderer : Written [error="unauthorized", error_description="Full authentication is required to access this resource"] as "application/json;charset=UTF-8" using [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter@1ed98b6d]
```

My `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` class is here:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Order(SecurityProperties.BASIC_AUTH_ORDER)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final UserDetailsAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

    @Autowired
    public WebSecurityConfig(UserDetailsAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider) {
        super(true);
        this.authenticationProvider = authenticationProvider;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        //http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        http
            .requestMatchers()
                .antMatchers("/login", "/logout", "/oauth/authorize", "/oauth/confirm_access", "/oauth/token")
                .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/login", "/logout", "/oauth/authorize", "/oauth/confirm_access", "/oauth/token").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .antMatcher("/**")
            .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
            .exceptionHandling()
                .accessDeniedHandler(new OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler());
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean credentialValidationFilter() {
        FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();

        filterRegistrationBean.setFilter(new CredentialValidationFilter());
        filterRegistrationBean.setUrlPatterns(Lists.newArrayList("/oauth/token"));
        filterRegistrationBean.setName("Request body credentials filter");
        filterRegistrationBean.setOrder(1);

        return filterRegistrationBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean tenantExtractionFilter() {
        FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();

        filterRegistrationBean.setFilter(new TenantExtractionFilter());
        filterRegistrationBean.setUrlPatterns(Lists.newArrayList("/*"));
        filterRegistrationBean.setName("Current tenant name extraction filter");
        filterRegistrationBean.setOrder(1);

        HashMap filterConfig = new HashMap();
        filterConfig.put(Parameter.EXCLUDED_URLS, "/oauth/token");
        filterRegistrationBean.setInitParameters(filterConfig);

        return filterRegistrationBean;
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

My AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter class is here;

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    private final DataSource dataSource;
    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    private final ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public AuthorizationServerConfiguration(DataSource dataSource, AuthenticationManager authenticationManager,
                                            ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
        this.clientDetailsService = clientDetailsService;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.withClientDetails(this.clientDetailsService);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) {
        endpoints.authenticationManager(this.authenticationManager)
                //.pathMapping("/oauth/token", "/oauth/tenant/token")
                .tokenServices(tokenServices())
                .allowedTokenEndpointRequestMethods(HttpMethod.GET, HttpMethod.POST)
                .setClientDetailsService(clientDetailsService);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {
        security.checkTokenAccess("permitAll()")
                .checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
    }

    @Bean
    @Transactional
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource);
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices() {
        DefaultTokenServices tokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
        tokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(true);
        tokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore());
        tokenServices.setReuseRefreshToken(false);
        tokenServices.setClientDetailsService(clientDetailsService);
        return tokenServices;
    }
}
```

My ClientConfiguration class is here;

```
@Configuration
public class ClientConfiguration {

    private final LoadBalancerClient loadBalancerClient;

    @Autowired
    public ClientConfiguration(LoadBalancerClient client) {
        this.loadBalancerClient = client;
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService(ClientRepository clientRepository){
        return clientId -> clientRepository
                .findByClientId(clientId)
                .map(
                        client -> {
                            BaseClientDetails details = new BaseClientDetails(client.getClientId(),
                                    null, client.getScope(), client.getAuthorizedGrantTypes(), client
                                    .getAuthorities());
                            details.setClientSecret(client.getClientSecret());
                            details.setAccessTokenValiditySeconds(client.getAccessTokenValidity());
                            details.setRefreshTokenValiditySeconds(client.getRefreshTokenValidity());

                            return details;
                        })
                .orElseThrow(
                        () -> new ClientRegistrationException(String.format(
                                "no client %s registered", clientId)));
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no controller method for /uaa. 
I use following configurations for that : server.port.servlet.contextPath= /uaa
By the way I use OAuth2

Comment: I have already setted logging.level.org.springframework.security = DEBUG

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem; deleted my ClientConfiguration class and implemented following class

```
@Service
public class CustomClientDetailsService implements ClientDetailsService {

    private ClientRepository clientRepository;

    @Autowired
    public CustomClientDetailsService(ClientRepository clientRepository) {
        this.clientRepository = clientRepository;
    }

    /**
     * Load a client by the client id. This method must not return null.
     *
     * @param clientId The client id.
     * @return The client details (never null).
     * @throws ClientRegistrationException If the client account is locked, expired, disabled, or invalid for any other reason.
     */
    @Override
    public ClientDetails loadClientByClientId(String clientId) throws ClientRegistrationException {
        return clientRepository
                .findByClientId(clientId)
                .map(
                        client -> {
                            BaseClientDetails details = new BaseClientDetails(client.getClientId(),
                                    null, client.getScope(), client.getAuthorizedGrantTypes(), client
                                    .getAuthorities());
                            details.setClientSecret(client.getClientSecret());
                            details.setAccessTokenValiditySeconds(client.getAccessTokenValidity());
                            details.setRefreshTokenValiditySeconds(client.getRefreshTokenValidity());

                            return details;
                        })
                .orElseThrow(
                        () -> new ClientRegistrationException(String.format(
                                "no client %s registered", clientId)));
    }
}
```